# iCarousel performance issue with UITableView (iPad master-detail UI)

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, icarousel

I am currently using a master-detail iPad UI: inside a **UISplitViewController** I have the left (master) side contain a **UITableViewController**, and the right (detail) side contains an **iCarousel**. See attached image.

**Problem:** When scrolling the table view **WHILE** the carousel **is still animating** The table view scrolls and decelerates smoothly, and the iCarousel scrolls in a sluggish (that is, barely animating at all) fashion.

What can one do to improve the iCarousel's animation "smoothness" when animating in concurrence to a table view animating/decelerating?

[image]

Points for consideration:

1. Tested on iPad 1 (non-retina), iPad 4G (retina), and in simulator retina and non retina, same results in all platforms.
2. It does not seem to matter whether you first drag the carousel and then the table or in the other order, the table view always takes "precedence", and iCarousel's smooth animation performance seems to go *^&k!.

Comment: I have no idea about iCarousel, but it sounds like whatever drives its animation is scheduled in the "wrong" run loop mode. Set it to `NSRunLoopCommonModes ` and it should work.

Comment: The control is a (wonderful!) cover flow-like controller named "iCarousel". It seems to animate using an 'NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats', and it intermittently uses '[_timer invalidate]' also '[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES]' and '[CATransaction setDisableActions:NO]' no scheduling in any run loop mode / type seems to be used in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the timer that drives the animation, is scheduled in the default run loop mode, which means that the timer won't fire while you scroll in a `UIScrollView` (which the table view inherits from). To solve this problem, you have to modify the iCarousel code (line 1737, `startAnimation`). Add the following:

`[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];`

Comment: @RabinDev You are right, sorry! I typed that into SO while trying to eat something, clearly not one of my best ideas! :p

Comment: BTW, got a nice friendly email reply from the author of the mentioned controller as I posted this same question in the github issue tracker for the iCarousel controller. He suggested this solution also. So i guess this makes this answer an even "betterer" one.